# c# skype4com how to write a status near my online icon?

Tags: c#, skype4com

I am using skype4com dll. Is there a way I can change my status (i mean i would like to add a link,or write a status)  using skype4com? How can I do that? I know TUserStatus can help you to change from online to offine or invisible mode. But what about adding a message to the status? Thx folks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called MoodText and is located on the Profile interface.

```
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace SO5673842
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var skype = new Skype();
            skype.CurrentUserProfile.MoodText = "Hello!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot!! I will try it. Is there a way to transfer a file or to accept a file? Should i use user32dll and skype4com.dll? And the second question how can i accept calls or make a call? Do you know the c# code for this? THX!! Really appreciate:).

Comment: Or is there a way to send sms messages using skype4com and the phone number to that person? THX A LOT!

Comment: @Alex: I think you should use Google first, SO later